# Hibernate, Abstract classes and common Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I got an abstract class called `AbstractUser` and two subclasses `Organisation` and `User`. `Organisation` got the same as `User` but with additional features.

I have another class aswell called `notes`

`Organisation` can create `notes` 
And `user` can save notes. So notes belong to one `Organisation` but can be saved by alot of `user` objects

Is it possible to properly setup the `notes` to both have a ManyToMany relation with `user` and a ManyToOne with organisation?

I'd pretty much like a relation below, where

```
     note_user                              note_organisation
note_id    user_id   id(incremented)    note_id     organisation_id
  1          4            1               1               2
  1          3            2               2               2
  2          3            3               3               3
```

This is what I've got so far.
Organisation:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long OrganisationId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "organisation_note", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "OrganisationId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "note_id") })
    private Set<Note> bookmarks = new HashSet<>();
```

user:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
private long userId;

@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }  )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_note",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "note_id")})
    private Set<Note> notes = new HashSet<>();
```

note:

```
@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long projectId; 

//Is this even necessary? I never save users to notes
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Above works. But it's behaving very very strangely. I get duplicated rows all the time when I create a note or save a note with a user. This will also allow me to create two notes with an organisation object, but the third will give me an error saying duplicate key for primary, same primary as the first note created. Is there anything I can do make my code more consistent and reliable?

Saving objects:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();    
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(entity);
        try {
            session.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error flushing");
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Which inheritance strategy do you use ? How do you save data (notes) to database in hibernate ?

Comment: @BillBilal I have a class called AbstractUser, and this is my reference object and I use that to save and retrieve objects of User and Organisation. And with Notes I just have a regular class. No extends.

Comment: There is a way in hibernate to define inheritance. You may use @MappedSuperclass annotation in your abstract class so that hibernate knows that it is a super class.

Comment: You may also use @Inheritance and define a strategy. Show as how do you save entities in database. For example when you say 'I get duplicated rows all the time when I create a note or save a note with a user' how do you save a note, what is duplicated ?

Comment: @BillBilal I updated my post with the saving method.